# Hive inequality join using between operator

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive

We have a query similar to the below: (partition_date is our tables partition)

```
SELECT * FROM A
JOIN B 
where partition_date > B.last_runtime;
```

We realized that by placing the condition in the `where` clause it is causing a full table scan so we need to place it in the `JOIN` as an `ON`.

The problem with this is Hive does not support inequality joins so was thinking of using `BETWEEN` operator like the below:

```
Select * from A
JOIN B ON par_date between B.last_runtime and '99999999';
```

> this is giving us the error: Both left and right aliases encountered
>   in JOIN ''99999999''

If I replace B.last_runtime with an actual value, say '20160310' it works okay...

any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you replace B.last_runtime with a constant, you no longer have a join condition, rather a "where" condition on A.

Answer (score 0):

`A BETWEEN B AND C` translates to *A is greater than or equal to B AND A less than or equal to C*, so I think it's still an non-equijoin.

However, I cannot explain the meaning of the error message. It's thrown [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/0d379021e7b1ef76572bc856d1206ed42148d137/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/optimizer/calcite/translator/JoinCondTypeCheckProcFactory.java#L119), if you'd like to analyze the source code:

```
private static boolean hasTableAlias(JoinTypeCheckCtx ctx, String tabName, ASTNode expr)
    throws SemanticException {
  int tblAliasCnt = 0;
  for (RowResolver rr : ctx.getInputRRList()) {
    if (rr.hasTableAlias(tabName))
      tblAliasCnt++;
  }

  if (tblAliasCnt > 1) {
    throw new SemanticException(ErrorMsg.INVALID_JOIN_CONDITION_1.getMsg(expr));
  }

  return (tblAliasCnt == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive will not support any operations like `>`,`<`,`<=`,`>=` during join condition. Might be `left` or `right` join. Here's an example:

```
select A.Name, A.Address, B.salary from Person_details as A left join Person_earnings as B on (B.salary > 15000)
```

**Instead**

```
select A.Name, A.Address, B.salary from Person_details as A left join Person_earnings as B on (A.Id=B.Id) where B.salary > 15000
```

> First, An equality operation should be done, later other conditions can be applied. As Hive is used on large data sets it only supports equality condition first.